# How to design routes when dealing with Laravel API instead of returning Laravel views?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, google-amp

So far I've been building Laravel and Django apps that return views or templates from backend. So far so good.

However, I'm now building a Laravel API that gets called from a frontend [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) code.

In the old ways I do this in Laravel:
From `web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Or I can return the view from the controller.

However, if the Laravel app is an API that returns JSON, how can I design URLs?

Basically, if someone clicks a link on the homepage that should take hime to a user profile, say:

```
/user/{id}
```

Where will I decide how this URL looks like and which endpoint to call?

Comment: you can add the routes in `api.php` which I believe automatically prefixes the urls with `api`. i.e., `api/user/{id}`

Comment: I know but this designs the API endpoint routes. I want to design the frontend routes.

Comment: How is frontend related to API?

Comment: @Wreigh do I do that in web.php and serve my AMP pages as if they were Laravel views that call the API endpoints? What I have in mind is to keep frontend and backend as seperate systems.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with AMP. What do you intend to return(response) on your *front end* routes?

Comment: @kerbholz it's not. I want to have a standalone frontend that calls the api endpoints, but where do I design the URLs?

Comment: I want frontend code that could be vanilla html, css, js that calls the API endpoints which in turn return JSON to frontend.

Comment: Your frontend routes are defined in `routes/web.php`, your API routes in `routes/api.php`, as @Wreigh wrote.

Comment: I'm confused. You want to return html/css/js but it's not a view?

Comment: I can do that I guess but what I was having in mind is to have a standalone frontend, similar to an iOS or an Android whom code does not live inside the Laravel app. I want something similar but as a Web frontend.

Comment: @Wreigh I want to have two seperate systems. One backend (Laravel API) and one frontend (Web app).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same route syntax, but instead of returning a view, you return a [json response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses).

```
Route::get('api/user', function () {
    $data = ['status' => 'success', 'data' => 'stuff'];
    return response()->json($data);
});
```

Take a look at [the response documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses) for all available types of responses.

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrapped my head around this. At least I think so.

in `web.php` I have a set of Closures with the URLs that I want. These Closures return views with no data. Similar to this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And then in the view I call the API endpoints as specified in `api.php` to render the data that I need in the view.

```
// List activities
Route::get('activities', 'ActivityController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.3 and above provides the seperate route file `routes/api.php`, where you can write all routes related to your api requests.

for controller just create a seperate folder in controller folder named as 'Api' and create api related controller in that.

and from there you can write function for corresponding routes. and return json as 
`return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);`

Or you can use https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules package to create a sepperate api module in laravel.